# How to access class with interface from DLL?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, dynamic-programming

I'm developing a program that uses plugins. All plugins are classes that inherits from KrotAPI.IKrotAPI interface. The interface is stored in krotapi.cs file, that is common for both host's csproj and every plugins' *.csproj.

The host loads plugins using this code

```
dynamic LoadPlugin(Assembly asm)
{
  foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
  {
    if (type.GetInterface("KrotAPI.IKrotPlugin") != null)
    {
      PluginType = type;
      dynamic inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
      KrotAPI.IKrotPlugin inst2 = inst as KrotAPI.IKrotPlugin;
      if (inst2 == null) return inst;
      Console.WriteLine("Link to API is set up.");
      return inst2;
    }
  }
  throw new Exception("There are no valid plugin(s) in the DLL.");
}
```

The `inst2` is always null, and I am forced to use slow and buggy dynamic calls. How to make it like `inst`, but with `KrotAPI.IKrotPlugin` type?

---

Second question on almost same topic.
Some plugins' functions returns an result of type KrotAPI.FindData (it's an structure, that is stored in above krotapi.cs file). But i cannot access it:

```
dynamic fd = new KrotAPI.FindData();
if (NextItemInfo != null) //NextItemInfo is an instance of that struct
    fd = NextItemInfo;
listBox1.Items.Add(fd.FileName);
```

On last row NET Framework throws this exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
>   'System.ValueType' does not contain a definition for 'FileName'

however the FileName field is hardcoded in the struct and certainly not a null, or

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException
>   An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation

if I replace the last line with `KrotAPI.FindData fd2 = (KrotAPI.FindData) fd; listBox1.Items.Add(fd2.FileName);`.

WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `IKrotAPI` interface defined in your host and your plugins. This means that they are not the same interface. The containing assembly is part of the interface's full identity. Each of your plugins is actually implementing an interface that is defined within it's own assembly, which is not the same interface that is defined within the host assembly.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Have your plugins reference the host assembly for the `IKrotAPI` interface.
2. Create a third assembly just for the interfaces and data types (e.g. `KrotAPI.FindData`) that are common to both host and server.

I personally prefer the second approach. It allows you to upgrade your host assembly without invalidating the existing plugins. To use a common naming convention for this sort of assembly, this third assembly might be called something like `KrotAPI`. I tend to think of an "API" as the set of interfaces and data types that someone (i.e. a plugin developer) would code against, but all actual runnable code would, in your case, be in either the host or the plugin.

Comment: Thanks! What troubles may occur when I choose first way, and some plugin(s) will be older or newer than the host exe? Currently, I'm see it better because there are no need to place within every plugin's directory a KrotAPI.dll file, and when there are no Krot.exe in the plugin's directory, all still working (as I assume, the plugins are using assembly that is already loaded in memory).

Comment: The assembly version number is part of the assembly's identity, which is then a part of the interface's identity. This means that if you update the version number of the host assembly, the interface defined by that assembly is no longer the interface that was used by the plugin assemblies. This can be mitigated somewhat through binding redirects.

Comment: You wouldn't need the API assembly in every plugin's directory. If you are using the default AppDomain, you can just force the the host application to load the API assembly before loading any of the plugins, and then each plugin will just use the already-loaded API assembly. You can force the loading of the assembly a number of ways (I usually use an empty, static method). If you are isolating each of your plugins in a separate AppDomain, it's a little more work, but you can still get all of the plugins to use a central API assembly.